# Drupal how to add a search filter to admin content page

Tags: search, drupal, admin

I've never used Drupal before (development or managing content). I was asked to extend the admin content page to have a filter and simply don't know enough to get moving quickly.

Can anyone tell me if adding a search by text filter in the admin content area requires code or is there a CMS feature like adding a node for this task.

If code is required, is there something like a hook for this area? Not sure where to start. I will be investigating on my own but pointers to get  me oriented to Drupal would help.

Comment: Not getting any answers, but so far I'm looking through a file modules/node.admin.inc which has the options on the content page currently.

It looks like the answer may be that I should create my own module that implements hook_form. So that's what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Drupal provides search mechanism ready to use. But there are also additional module which can improve search experience. You don't need any coding to use that search. You already have search form block ready to use.

Go to `Structure -> Blocks` and find block called "**Search form**". Now all you have to do is to put that block in some region and it will appear on front-end. Of course if it's not already styled by your theme it may be needed to put some extra CSS to make it look nice. There are also some template files which you can override and put some your HTML if you need.
There's also template file for search results page (which of course will work out of box also).

You may also need to create new block region if you want to place your form at some specific place, not covered by any existing region defined by your theme (easy thing to do!).

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful. My google search for admin customization was not very successful.

Though, I may still need to make something custom since the search results don't act like a back-end filter. This built in search re-directs me to the front-end. (I'll look around settings to see if there's any fix for this)

Comment: In Drupal 10 blocks are now located in Views, and allow for editing fields and filters for /admin/content

Answer (score 0):

See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/30633/101329, the "[Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views)" module lets you configure the search form as you like.